ERROR [ExceptionHandler] nest cant resolve dependencies of the MongooseCoreModule (MongooseConnectionName, ?)
app.module.ts:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService} from './app.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1/nest')],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService]
})
export class AppModule {}

I am new to nestjs, after adding this line MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1/nest'), I keep getting this error. Is there anything i miss out?
Error: ERROR [ExceptionHandler] nest cant resolve dependencies of the MongooseCoreModule (MongooseConnectionName, ?) Please make sure that the argument ModuleRef at index[1] is available in the MongooseCoreModule context.
